# How to change atom's package syntax?

Tags: coffeescript, package, atom-editor

I am trying to write a atom package, and in the manual it said

> Note: By default, the package generator emits JavaScript. You can change this to CoffeeScript to follow along better with this tutorial. In the Settings View, go to the package-generator settings and change the "Package Syntax" setting to "CoffeeScript".

but I didn't find package-generator settings in the settings view,in the settings view there are

- Core
- Editor
- Keybindings
- Packages
- Themes
- Updates
- Install

I can find nothing about package generator, how can I change the Package Syntax, does it writed in some setting file?

My atom version is 1.15.0 x64  for debian/ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look in the *Packages* pane in the Settings View? Note that bundled packages are listed below third-party packages!

Comment: Thanks, I found it. I didn't realize that it means settings of a "package-generator" package.